# Firebase Hosting support for HTTP/2 and SNI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Received this email from Firebase today:

[image]

So what should I do?

I use Digital Ocean DNS.

At the moment, I CNAME to my app `khophi-auth.firebaseapp.com` like so in Digital Ocean:

```
name | hostname 
code | khophi-auth.firebaseapp.com.
```

accessible eventually at `code.khophi.co`

So the instructions in the email, what does it want me to do? Change what to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from comments on blog post they say to point to

`khophi-auth.firebaseapp.com -> s-sni.firebaseapp.com`

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/http2-comes-to-firebase-hosting.html

Comment: This works for me.  Seems Firebase are doing the domain to project resolution at their end rather than you having to specify it in your cname like the old method did, hence the generic s-sni.